# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Ausrüstungswichtigkeit" und "Die Wichtigkeit der Ausrüstung"?

Tags: standard-german

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen **Ausrüstungswichtigkeit** und **Die Wichtigkeit der Ausrüstung**?

Wann benutzen wir Genitiv und wann Komposita?

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you gave an example of a word that is actually used. *"Ausrüstungswichtigkeit"* did never occur to me and it sounds quite unidiomatic to me. I think no german native speaker would say something like *"Die Ausrüstungswichtigkeit kann nicht genug betont werden."*

Comment: "Ausrüstungswichtigkeit" ist für mich nicht eindeutig und kann die Wichtigkeit des (gut) Ausrüstens oder die Wichtigkeit der (richtigen) Ausrüstung bedeuten.

Answer (score 3):

Das ist eine Stilfrage.

Komposita fassen einen größeren Zusammenhang zu einem einzigen Begriff zusammen. Man sollte sie also nur verwenden, wenn man wirklich einen neuen Begriff bilden will.

Wenn man in einem Text ständig neue Komposita bildet und sie dann nur einmal benutzt, klingt das sehr wichtigtuerisch und gleichzeitig ungeschickt. Als Nicht-Muttersprachler hast du zudem praktisch keine Chance, zu wissen, ob ein Kompositum bereits existiert, und somit einen gängigen Begriff darstellt.

Es ist im Zweifel klüger, eine Umschreibung mit Genitivattributen zu verwenden.

Comment: "Als Nicht-Muttersprachler hast du zudem praktisch keine Chance, zu wissen..."  Ein wenig arrogant, meinst du nicht?

Answer (score 2):

"Ausrüstungswichtigkeit" erinnert sehr an "Kriegswichtigkeit", vor allem weil "(sich) rüsten" auch bedeutet, (s)eine Armee zu bewaffnen.

Das Wort "[kriegswichtig](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kriegswichtig)" heißt nicht, dass der Krieg wichtig ist. Vielmehr ist kriegswichtig, was *für* den Krieg, die Kriegsführung wichtig ist. Komposita sind also auch **ungenauer**.

Das Wort "kriegswichtig" wird besonders im Zusammenhang mit den Nazis im 2. Weltkrieg gebraucht, die es auch selbst verwendeten[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/kriegswichtig).